# Cannot resolve symbol "TestKit"

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, akka-testkit, testkit

`Getting started with "Testing Akka Actors"`

I think there is something wrong with my `"akka-testkit"` library-dependency. I copied it from [`Lightbend Testing Classic Actors`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/testing.html)

**build.sbt**

```
version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.12.7"

val akkaVersion = "2.5.13"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % akkaVersion,
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % akkaVersion % Test
)
```

**.scala**

```
package part3testing

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.testkit.TestKit

class BasicSpec extends TestKit(ActorSystem("BasicSpec")){

}
```

Comment: What is giving such error? SBT compilation? Your IDE?

Comment: IDE error. I guess the dependency is not correct?

Comment: Try with SBT first. `sbt compile`

Comment: Is your `.scala` file in `src/test/scala/part3testing`?

Comment: nope it's in src/main/scala/

Comment: @GaëlJ did sbt compile got `object testkit is not a member of package akka` ...

`***import akka.testkit.{ImplicitSender, TestKit}***`

Comment: @LeviRamsey If we write % Test at the end of the library dependency, the .scala file should be inside `src/test/scala/part3testing`? as this path is already in my project..
_How to write our dependency when `.scala` is in `src/main/scala`?_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marking a dependency as `% Test` means that only code in the test directories (by default, `src/test`) will depend on it.  Main application code (by default in `src/main`) does not depend on test-scope dependencies; the benefit of this is that the test dependencies aren't needed for distributing/deploying the built software so don't get included or need to be provided.

Comment: I removed `%Test` from `"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % akkaVersion % Test` ,  did refresh and it works. Thanks

Comment: @Always_A_Learner you should probably not use test dependencies in main code, unless you are writing a tests library maybe?